# Process for mod of a variable that follows some Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Assuming a variable $v$ follows some `Stochastic Process` as below -

$dv=\mu v dt + \sigma v dW_t, v \in \left( -\infty, \infty \right) $

I want to get the process of $|v|$

How can I use the `ito's lemma` in this context given that the function $|v|$ is not smooth?

Comment: Can the GBM take negative values? You can use Ito's lemma with confidence - please see here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55028/the-most-general-conditions-under-which-ito-lemma-holds/55030?noredirect=1#comment80010_55030

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I removed that. But my question is to apply Ito's lemma, how can I calculate $\frac{d|v|}{dv}$ given it doesnt exist at $v=0$?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, I think. Firstly, if $v=v(t,\omega)$ is a stochastic process, you can't compute $\frac{d|v|}{dv}$. SDEs may look like differential equations but are actually integral equations. Secondly, if $dv=\mu vdt+\sigma vdW_t$, then $v$ is a geometric Brownian motion and thus positive, i.e.  $|v(t,\omega)|=v(t,\omega)$ for all $t,\omega$. So, if $v$ is supposed to be a general stochastic process, you ought to delete this equation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for extended Ito formula (based on Tanaka's formula).

Bjork's [The Pedestrian’s Guide to Local Time](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.08912.pdf) should be useful.